# What does abutted semicolons mean in Windows 10 PATH?

Tags: windows, path

I installed Anaconda on Windows 10.  When I run Spyder and
query the `PATH` environment variables, it contains a pair
of abutted semicolons.  Here is `PATH`, with each semicolon
followed by a new line for clarity:

```
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39;
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library\bin;
C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\Scripts;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2023a\runtime\win64;
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2023a\bin;
C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
;
C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

There is a lone semicolon on the 2nd last line.  What does this mean?
Does it mean the same as `.;`?  The reason I ask is because the Conda
environment has `.;` as the 2nd last directory in `PATH`, while the
others are the same.

**Afternote 2023-09-11:** The current working directory `.` might have been removed because Windows automatically searches the current directory before the paths in the `PATH` variable, as described [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html) (Section 5: "current directory is included in Windows' PATH implicitly").  This is not a formal Microsoft page, however, and it also leaves open the question of why the extra `;` is not removed along with the `.`.

Comment: This question is more for superuser.com

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, Simon.  I will certainly post there, but my googling shows that StackOverflow is more suitable for coding/scripting and development, while SuperUser is for app-level end users.  Would you please elaborate on your thinking?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a specific thinking beyond the fact this is not really a development question, there's no language, scriping nor coding involved in it, for ex: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them. How the PATH is displayed by a specific app doesn't really matter. Run "SET" from a command line, or use the Windows' env variable editor.

Comment: OK, I'll post there.  It still feels off in that the cited Q&A deals with where Window searches for user level apps.  In contrast the context of my question is more the interoperation between development environments, i.e., Conda environment for managing development packages vs. Spyder environment for code development.  Or rather, the latter is an exploratory analysis environment that can easily prototype an app for later implementation -- in the same language (Python).  The REPL muddies the boundary between development and user level.  Thanks for elaborating on your rationale.

Comment: P.S. I'm wondering if it's still worthwhile posting it to SuperUser, since I think I found the answer in my addendum to the originally posted question ("Afternote 2023-09-11").  The only thing is that the cited page is not a formal Microsoft documentation of the behaviour, and it still leaves dangling loose ends.

Comment: @user2153235 If you change your afternote to an answer, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: @Ellen Spertus: I appreciate that, but I'm not all that comfortable taking it.  There just seem to be too many caveats in my last comment.  The real bounty should go to someone who can find the Microsoft document, even if they don't figure out why the extra `;` was not removed.  The latter might just be how the scripts were written for PySpark.  Thanks!  (Hopefully you get the bounty back?  Not that you need it)

Comment: FWIW, the "afternote" quotes a somewhat confused source.  `.` is not "implicitly included in the `PATH` variable"  The PATH variable is only one of a fairly lengthy list of places Windows searches, and "current working directory" is also on that list.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thanks.  I've revised the "afternote".

Comment: It seems like the jokes of StackOverflow never end with me! Last time, I received a bounty with a score of 500, but when the time was up, even though my answer was selected, I didn't receive it without any explanation. And this time, too, the same thing happened with this bounty.

If you don't want to give the score, why do you even start a bounty?

Comment: @Freeman: Sorry, I only have the vaguest sense of how bounties work.  Isn't it automatic if you make it on time?  I *think* you made it on time, but I'm not entirely sure.  What if the countdown isn't accurate due to internet limitations?  On many forums, I see approximations of when a question/answer/comment is posted or updated.

Comment: Thnx bro, my objection was not towards you. In my opinion, @EllenSpertus should have come and verified, but she didn't. Of course, 50 points are not that important. Last time, my 500 points were not given.
In the end, I'm glad that your problem was resolved and I found a new friend.
Good luck, my friend.

Comment: I appreciate the Microsoft references for substantiation of the answer.  As for bounties, I'm learning that having an answer marked on-time isn't enough, and that verification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think,the lone semicolon in the PATH variable means there's an empty directory listed. But don't worry, it doesn't really affect anything. You can just ignore it. The semicolon itself doesn't have any special meaning like the dot (.) which represents the current directory.

In contrast, the Conda environment could exist in OSs other than Windows.  Thus `.;` is included in the PATH to make it easier to run programs in the current directory without typing the whole path.

Again, in Windows, the current directory isn't automatically included in the PATH because it is unnecessary. Adding `.;` explicitly includes the current directory for searching programs in the Conda environment for those cases when it is hosted by a non-Windows OS.

As for why the `.` (current directory) might have been removed from the PATH, it could be because Windows already searches `.` by default. But we can't say for sure why the extra semicolon is still there.

References :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/path

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to an authoritative source for the statement that the current directory isn't automatically included in Windows?  In my "Afternote 2023-09-11", I cite a non-authoritative source saying the opposite.  In my mind, an authoritative source is either Microsoft or an online identity with a well established record of expertise.  Thanks.

Comment: For me, only the 1st link worked, and I couldn't find anything about current directory.  I got a page-not-found for the remaining 3 links.

Comment: It's strange, it's not showing for me either and it gives a 404 error. I apologize, let me provide two more links, But in general including the current directory in the PATH can pose security risks, especially if the current directory is set to a network location or if malicious files are present.for this reason, it is recommended to avoid including the current directory explicitly in the PATH.

(1)https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa

(2)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/path

Comment: I understand your description of the risk. Through this question, I'm only trying to establish the formal behaviour. Your answer says two things that seem to me like they are in opposition.  It says that in Windows. `.` isn't included automatically, but then you say that it is included by default.  Would be able to revise your answer to eliminate this contradiction?  Thanks.  Adding the links into your answer would also help.

Comment: In Windows, the current directory (represented by the dot ".") is not automatically included in the PATH variable.however, it is worth noting that Windows does include the current directory by default when searching for executables.Regarding the Conda environment, they include ".;" in the PATH to facilitate running programs in the current directory without specifying the full path.This addition explicitly includes the current directory for searching programs within the Conda environment.

Comment: As for the presence of an extra semicolon in the PATH variable, it could be due to an empty directory listed.however,this lone semicolon does not have any significant impact and can be safely ignored!!!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Freeman.  I tried to bring out these clarifications in making edits to your answer.  If you find them sensible, thanks if you would accept them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add again, if you can include the reference links in your answer, that would cover a key element of the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon by itself, as in ;, represents the current directory. In the context of the PATH environment variable, it essentially means "the current directory," which is usually the directory from which you are running a command.

So, in your PATH configuration, this ; between the two entries indicates that the current directory is included in the PATH.

Comment: I'm confused.  The `;` between directories serves to delimit directories.  It doesn't mean that `.` is in the `PATH`.  I'm wondering if the appearance of `;;` in `PATH` means that a PySpark script removed `.` from `PATH` because Windows already searches `.` by default, as explained by *Freeman*.  Perhaps the extra `;` was left behind by mistake (though as *Freeman* said, it has no effect).